# ¿Cómo aceptar únicamente un rango de letras y cancelar la entrada de números en C?

Tags: c, scanf

Me gustaría que mi código acepte únicamente las opciones disponibles que le doy al usuario por pregunta, por ejemplo, en la primera pregunta que solo sea capaz el usuario de ingresar las letras "a" y "b" y no otras letras. En alguna otra segunda pregunta lo mismo pero con las opciones "a", "b', "c", "d" y "e".

Agradecería mucho su ayuda y lo siento por tanta pregunta, gracias. ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char sexo;
    int suma;

    printf("Indica tu sexo.\n\na) Masculino\nb) Femenino\n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &sexo);

    switch (sexo){
    case 'a': suma = 50;break;
    case 'A': suma = 50;break;
    case 'b': suma = 30;break;
    case 'B': suma = 30;break;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No se si hay alguna forma de poner solo las letras que pones pero puedes poner un do while para que si no poner la opción correcta se repita el ciclo. Tomando tu ejemplo seria algo así.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
            
 int main(){
    char sexo;
    int suma;

printf("Indica tu sexo.\n\na) Masculino\nb) Femenino\n\n");
    
  do{

  scanf(" %c", &sexo);

  if(sexo!='a'&&'A'&& sexo!='b'&&'B'){
     printf("Opción incorrecta\a"); //la \a es para que suene un aviso
    }

}while(sexo!='a'&&'A'&& sexo!='b'&&'B');
    
 switch (sexo){
 case 'a': suma = 50;break;
 case 'A': suma = 50;break;
 case 'b': suma = 30;break;
 case 'B': suma = 30;break;
}
    
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

En el segundo caso en el `do while` pones un rango de letras en vez de poner letra por letra. Algo asi

```
do{
//El codigo que quieras
}while(sexo<'a'&&sexo>'e');
```

Comment: Justo había intentado un do while pero el problema que tenia es que la letra "a" y "A" me las aceptaba sin problema pero la "b" y "B" y pensaba que era algún error mío por escribir mal el do while pero no, justo lo mismo pasa acá. ):

Comment: okey si ya ,e he dado cuenta donde está el error

Comment: ahora mismo te corrijo el codigo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y estar atento, creí que no se podría con un do while pero ya veo que sí.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes anidar en un for y en el caso de los cases si a y A se comportan igual puedes juntarlos

```
char sexo;
int suma;
scanf(" %c", &sexo);
int flag = 0;
for (; flag == 1;)
{
    switch(sexo)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            suma = 50;
            flag=1;
            break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            suma = 30;
            flag=1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Indica tu sexo.\n\na) Masculino\nb) Femenino\n\n");
            scanf(" %c", &sexo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He realizado el siguiente código que creo puede resolver lo que pretendes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_QUESTIONS 2

char *Preguntas[MAX_QUESTIONS] = 
{ 
  "Indica tu sexo.\n\na) Masculino\nb) Femenino\n\n",
  "Indica tu edad.\n\na) Menos de 20 años\nb) Entre 20 y 30 años\n\nc) Más de 30 años\n\n" 
};
                 
char *Respuestas[MAX_QUESTIONS]= 
{
  "abAB",
  "abcABC"  
};

/* Valida si la respuesta es permitida */ 
int IsValidAnswer(char charAnswer, int numQuestion);

int main()
{
    char charAnswer;

    int numQuestion = 0;

    /* Este WHILE nos permite recorrer el cuestionario */
    while (numQuestion != MAX_QUESTIONS)
    {
        int nextQuestion = 0;
        /* Este WHILE formula la pregunta y nos fuerza a dar una respuesta permitida */
        while (!nextQuestion)
        {
            printf("%s", Preguntas[numQuestion]);
            scanf(" %c", &charAnswer);
        
            nextQuestion = IsValidAnswer(charAnswer, numQuestion);
        }
    
        numQuestion++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int IsValidAnswer(char charAnswer, int numQuestion)
{
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(Respuestas[numQuestion]); i++)
    {
        if (Respuestas[numQuestion][i] == charAnswer) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

He creado dos arreglos, uno con las preguntas y otro con las posibles respuestas. Luego ha sido necesario crear una función que determina si la respuesta dada está entre las posibles respuestas, lo que nos simplifica enormemente el código si queremos extender el cuestionario.

El código permite ampliar el cuestionario así como las respuestas posibles para cada pregunta. Se me ocurre que podría crearse otro arreglo que guarde las respuestas dadas por el usuario para evaluarlas.

Espero te ayude en lo que pretendías.